# C#: Implementing Licencing in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, licensing

I recently developed a win form application in C#. Now application is complete and working fine as expected. Now i want to implement licensing feature in it i.e either user buy license key or simply run trial version that expire after some time. Since i have very few time left in Deployment so i prefer some already existing library that did the job for me. More preferable some open source one but paid version also works. In case if there is no such existing solution then please guide me how to implement that.

Comment: Before someone closes this as a dupe, the only good dupe I found (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185158/copy-protection-and-licensing-tools) is 3 years old...

Comment: Licensing and Winforms are considerably older than 3 years, nothing has changed.  But this is a shopping question, off topic at all SE sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Eziriz's products](http://www.eziriz.com/). I use both of them, one for great obfuscation and the other for licensing. While the obfuscator itself has good support for licensing, IntelliLock is maybe something you'd want to look at for a robust solution.

Comment: Check the comments on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280256/what-is-an-exe-file-stub

Comment: That's weird... I've had good email support.